# Continuity Correction Problem.

Tags: statistics

We're supposed to use continuity correct with a random variable $X$ that can take only integer values , an equivalent expression for :

$4\leq10X<48$ is ?

Clearly , it should be $0.4\leq X<4.8$ ,

But the solution says , $0.5\leq X<4.5$ , why so ? HELP!

Comment: You should post more details of your problem (exercise), At the moment it is not clear why the solution is it as it is.

Comment: Unfortunately , only this much information is provided to me too..
Can't help it !  @calculus

Comment: drhab has the answer. Watch it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $X$ takes integer values the expression $4\leq10 X<48$ means actually that $X\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.

If $Y$ is a continuous "version" of $X$ then for integers $n$: $$X=n\iff Y\in[n-0.5,n+0.5)$$

This leads to:

$$X\in\{1,2,3,4\}\iff Y\in[0.5,4.5)$$